# Finding top 5 values based on another column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to find top 5 values of `category` column based while grouping `customer_id` column in pandas dataframe?

```
       customer_id     email                        address_id  name              category

0         411   NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org       416     NORMAN CURRIER      Scifi
1         411   NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org       416     NORMAN CURRIER      Action
2         411   NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org       416     NORMAN CURRIER      Sports
3         411   NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org       416     NORMAN CURRIER      Scifi
4         411   NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org       416     NORMAN CURRIER      Family
5         411   NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org       416     NORMAN CURRIER      Action
6         527   CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org          533     CORY MEEHAN         Documentary
7         527   CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org          533     CORY MEEHAN         Action
8         527   CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org          533     CORY MEEHAN         Sports
9         527   CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org          533     CORY MEEHAN         Scifi
10        527   CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org          533     CORY MEEHAN         Documentary
11        527   CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org          533     CORY MEEHAN         Sports
```

I want another column named `preferred_film_category` for each unique `customer_id` (**the top 5 values are based on how many times particular category occurs for each unique customer_id**)

**Expected Dataframe:**

```
       customer_id     email                     address_id    name       category      preferred_film_category   

0       411    NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org   416   NORMAN CURRIER    Scifi        Scifi, Action, Sports, Animation, Drama    
1       411    NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org   416   NORMAN CURRIER    Action       Scifi, Action, Sports, Animation, Drama 
2       411    NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org   416   NORMAN CURRIER    Sports       Scifi, Action, Sports, Animation, Drama 
3       411    NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org   416   NORMAN CURRIER    Scifi        Scifi, Action, Sports, Animation, Drama 
4       411    NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org   416   NORMAN CURRIER    Family       Scifi, Action, Sports, Animation, Drama 
5       411    NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org   416   NORMAN CURRIER    Action       Scifi, Action, Sports, Animation, Drama
6       527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org     533   CORY MEEHAN       Documentary  Documentary, Sports, Scifi, Action 
7       527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org     533   CORY MEEHAN       Action       Documentary, Sports, Scifi, Action 
8       527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org     533   CORY MEEHAN       Sports       Documentary, Sports, Scifi, Action 
9       527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org     533   CORY MEEHAN       Scifi        Documentary, Sports, Scifi, Action 
10      527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org     533   CORY MEEHAN       Documentary  Documentary, Sports, Scifi, Action 
11      527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org     533   CORY MEEHAN       Sports       Documentary, Sports, Scifi, Action
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas-dataframe-value-counts) + [`groupby nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html#pandas-core-groupby-seriesgroupby-nlargest) to get get the highest frequency categories, then [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) to convert to a string, then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) to merge back with the original DataFrame:

```
n = 2
df = df.join(
    df.value_counts(['customer_id', 'category'])
        .groupby(level=0).nlargest(n)
        .reset_index('category')
        .groupby(level=0)['category'].agg(', '.join)
        .rename('preferred_film_category'),
    on='customer_id'
)
```

`df`:

```
    customer_id                              email  address_id            name     category preferred_film_category
0           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER        Scifi           Action, Scifi
1           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Action           Action, Scifi
2           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Sports           Action, Scifi
3           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER        Scifi           Action, Scifi
4           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Family           Action, Scifi
5           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Action           Action, Scifi
6           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN  Documentary     Documentary, Sports
7           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN       Action     Documentary, Sports
8           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN       Sports     Documentary, Sports
9           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN        Scifi     Documentary, Sports
10          527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN  Documentary     Documentary, Sports
11          527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN       Sports     Documentary, Sports
```

*note `n` is set to `2` as each customer only has 4 unique values in `categrory` and so `5` does not demonstrate the functioning of the code. Change this to the desired value to keep (`5`).

---

DataFrame Used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id': [411, 411, 411, 411, 411, 411, 527, 527, 527, 527, 527, 527],
    'email': ['NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org',
              'NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org',
              'NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org',
              'NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org',
              'NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org',
              'NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org',
              'CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org',
              'CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org',
              'CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org',
              'CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org',
              'CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org',
              'CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org'],
    'address_id': [416, 416, 416, 416, 416, 416, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533, 533],
    'name': ['NORMAN CURRIER', 'NORMAN CURRIER', 'NORMAN CURRIER',
             'NORMAN CURRIER', 'NORMAN CURRIER', 'NORMAN CURRIER',
             'CORY MEEHAN', 'CORY MEEHAN', 'CORY MEEHAN', 'CORY MEEHAN',
             'CORY MEEHAN', 'CORY MEEHAN'],
    'category': ['Scifi', 'Action', 'Sports', 'Scifi', 'Family', 'Action',
                 'Documentary', 'Action', 'Sports', 'Scifi', 'Documentary',
                 'Sports']
})
```

`df`:

```
    customer_id                              email  address_id            name     category
0           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER        Scifi
1           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Action
2           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Sports
3           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER        Scifi
4           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Family
5           411  NORMAN.CURRIER@sakilacustomer.org         416  NORMAN CURRIER       Action
6           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN  Documentary
7           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN       Action
8           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN       Sports
9           527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN        Scifi
10          527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN  Documentary
11          527     CORY.MEEHAN@sakilacustomer.org         533     CORY MEEHAN       Sports
```