# How do I get the top 5 chosen values from a column based of another column?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which describes the width and height (Breedte x Hoogte) of window frames in 1 column and another column describes the name of the product (Vakvullingen).

[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6f9K.png)

I want to discover what the 5 most chosen width and height values are for every product (or less if they have less entries). I expect to see:

```
Vakvulling            | Breedte x Hoogte
  
mahonie verdiept      | 1000 x 1000, 1000 x 2762, 3176 x 2762, 2195 x 2363, 2800 x 1000
schuco living variant | 1911 x 2391, etc.
```

The question is really similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607540/count-the-number-of-occurrence-of-values-based-on-another-column), but I don't want to disregard the length and height. The question is also similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67939644/finding-top-5-values-based-on-another-column-pandas).

I think I'm almost there but I'm not sure how to continue. I've tried the following:

```
df_vakvullingen.value_counts(['Breedte x Hoogte', 'Vakvulling'])
```

Which gave me:

```
Breedte x Hoogte  Vakvulling                    
1000 x 1000       mahonie-verdiept-67x114-mm        323
1014 x 2220       meranti-bergingskozijn-57x69mm    176
1000 x 2200       mahonie-verdiept-67x114-mm        114
2000 x 2200       mahonie-verdiept-67x114-mm         95
1000 x 1200       mahonie-verdiept-67x114-mm         94
                                                   ... 
2800 x 2224       mahonie-verdiept-67x114-mm          1
2800 x 2250       gealan-s9000-nl                     1
                  standaard-houten-kozijn             1
2800 x 2265       gealan-s9000-nl                     1
2370 x 2370       mahonie-verdiept-67x114-mm          1
Length: 37957, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get counts for all entries

```
df.groupby(['Vakvulling'])['Breedte x Hoogte'].value_counts()
```

Limit by 5 using another group by and head().

```
df.groupby(['Vakvulling'])['Breedte x Hoogte'].value_counts().groupby('Vakvulling').head(5).to_frame()
```

Comment: No problem, if you are new to Stackoverflow please accept the answer by clicking on the check-mark.